# Camera for taking pictures of small objects?

Tags: camera

I would like to take pictures of objects about 10mm in size. The required image size is small, 640 * 480 is sufficient, but the object should fill most of the available image area.

The frame rate shall be a few images per second, but only the best image will stored and processed (not the intermediate images half-way between the previous object and the next one).

All objects pass by on a conveyor belt, the camera - object distance is fixed.

As I have no experience with Raspberry Pi cameras at all, which cameras and / or lenses would be suitable for this type of photography? Please advise.

Comment: Are you asking for specific purchasing recommendations, or to know what specifications should you check for when buying a camera for the Raspberry Pi? The [guidelines](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of this website indicate that questions shouldn't ask for purchasing recommendations.

Comment: I checked out several camera parts but I could not figure out whether a specific camera would support such close-up photography. When I use my mobile phone camera to take a picture of the objects, the picture is either in focus but the object is too small, or the object fills the picture but is out of focus. So, the requirement is beyond what my mobile phone camera can handle.

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy guide on [macrophotography with the Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/macro-photography-with-the-camera-board/) from the official Raspberry Pi website. I'd suggest you start looking there.

Comment: The guide suggests taking apart the Raspberry Pi camera board. While that might work as a last resort, I'd rather buy a camera which is designed for macrophotography.

Comment: For sure! :) I can tell you from experience though that the RPi camera is very easy to work with, and adjusting its lens is a simple task. However, it's good that you take a good look at what's out there available for you, so that you choose whatever suits best your application.